# How to find all complex numbers $z$ such that $z^3=\bar{z}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all complex numbers $z=a+bi$ such that $z^3=\bar{z}$.

I'll be happy if someone tell me with what steps I have to start solving this problem.

I try

$$(x+iy)^3=x^3-3xy^2+(3x^2y-y^3)i$$

then,

\begin{eqnarray}
x^3-3xy^2=x \\
3x^2y-y^2=-y 
\end{eqnarray}

If $y=0$, $x=0,x=-1,+1$

then if $y\neq 0$

O Other way?

write $z$ in polar form..

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547451/how-would-i-prove-that-if-an-integer-n2-then-barz-zn-1-has-n1-sol/1547466#1547466 (not strictly a duplicate, but the currently-existing answers also answer this question)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write $z=re^{ic},$ $z^3=r^3e^{3ic}$, $\bar z =re^{-ic}$. So you have $r=0$  or $ r=1$ and $3c=-c+2k\pi$. This implies that $c=k\pi/2, c=0,\pi/2,\pi, 3\pi/2$ and $z=0, 1,i,-1,-i$.

Answer (score 0):

First, $z=0$ is a trivial solution.  Then "write $z$ in polar form": $z=re^{it}$ with $r > 0$ and $t \in \Bbb R$.

Take modulus on both sides of $z^3=\bar z$ to see $r^3=r^{-1}\iff r^4=1$, so $r=1$.

Now
$$e^{3it}=e^{-it} \iff e^{4it}=1 \iff 4it = 2k\pi i \text{ with }k \in \Bbb Z \\
\iff t=\frac{k\pi}2 \text{ with }k \in \Bbb Z \iff z=e^{it}=i^k, k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$$