# Solve: $\overline{z}=z^n$

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$\overline{z}=z^n$$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

So I have started with moving the polar representation as the expression is in the n-th power

$$rcis(-\theta)=r^ncis(n\theta)$$

I can not multiply both sides in $r^{(-n)}$ as $n\in \mathbb{N}$ how should I continue?

Comment: What is $cis$? A complex exponential?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547451/how-would-i-prove-that-if-an-integer-n2-then-barz-zn-1-has-n1-sol/1547466#1547466

Comment: @Lovsovs $cis$ means $\cos\theta +i\sin \theta$

Comment: @JaideepKhare So yes, I guess. I've never seen this notation before, who uses it?

Comment: It's used almost everywhere as an abbreviation.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis_(mathematics) , It has Wiki too.Now you may also use it and spread it.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$, the answer is that $z$ can be any real number.

For $n>1$, observe that $|\overline{z}|=|z|$ so we must have $|z|=|z^n|$ which means that $z=0$ or $|z|=1$ (in $r\cdot cis\theta$ notation, $r=1$). This reduces the problem to a problem of rotations around the unit circle which can be easily solved.

Comment: So overall we have $n$ solutions?

Comment: @gbox $n+1$ solutions. The $n$ solutions on the unit circle, and also $0$.

Comment: But $0$ is not a solution of the unit circle?

Comment: @StellaBiderman $n+2$ actually, since $z^{n+1}=1$ has $n+1$ roots on the unit circle.

Comment: @gbox It is solution when $|z|=0$

Comment: @gbox $0$ is not on the unit circle because the unit circle is the set of all points with norm $1$.

Comment: @dxiv right! Forgot about incrementing the exponent.

Comment: @StellaBiderman "observe that $|\overline{z}|=|z|$ so we must have $|z|=|z^n|$" why "we must have $|z|=|z^n|$"?

Comment: You have $\overline{z}=z^n$. Taking the norm of both sides gives $|\overline{z}|=|z^n|$. The LHS is known to equal $|z|$ and the RHS is known to equal $|z|^n$.

Comment: @dxiv Why it is $z^{n+1}=1$ and not $z^{n}=1$?

Comment: @gbox Solutions other than $z=0$ have $|z|=1\,$. Therefore $z \bar z = |z|^2 = 1\,$, so $\bar z = \cfrac{1}{z}$ and the equation becomes $\cfrac{1}{z}=z^n \iff z^{n+1}=1\,$.